# Configuring a RAID10 on Xubuntu, UEFI system

Tags: xubuntu, uefi, raid

My 'system' personal experiences from the past:
- fresh install Windows
- fresh install GNU/Linux
- dual boot MBR Windows/Linux
I am not an expert; this is my first RAID installation attempt and I still don't have a rock-solid knowledge of concepts like "UEFI" and "MBR".

As of today, I'm currently trying to get Xubuntu installed on a simple RAID10 array.

I have a dedicated computer, a **UEFI**+**Legacy** supporting motherboard, **4 hard drives** (sda, sdb, sdc, sdd ; 1TB each), a bootable USB with the **xubuntu16.04** iso.

I wanted to keep everything as simple as possible so I tried:
boot from live USB "Try xUbuntu"
use cfdisk to format as follow :

```
/dev/sda1 --> 50Mb (Type = Linux filesystem)
/dev/sda2 --> 930.5G (Type = Linux RAID)
/dev/sda3 --> 1G (Type = Linux swap)
/dev/sdb1 --> 930.5G (Type = Linux RAID)
/dev/sdb2 --> 1G (Type = Linux swap)
/dev/sdc1 --> 930.5G (Type = Linux RAID)
/dev/sdc2 --> 1G (Type = Linux swap)
/dev/sdd1 --> 930.5G (Type = Linux RAID)
/dev/sdd2 --> 1G (Type = Linux swap)
```

Install and use mdadm to create /dev/md0

```
mdadm -v --create /dev/md0 --level=raid10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

Format the newly created array to XFS file system (mkfs.xfs /dev/md0)

Launch Xubuntu installer

When partitioning
/dev/sda1 is formatted to ext3 and flagged as "/boot" ;
/dev/md0 is let to xfs and flagged as "/" ;
1Gb partitions are set as Swap areas.

Multiple errors at the installation's end ; I performed anyway the mounting of the RAID into the new install:

```
mkdir /myraid
mount /dev/md0 /myraid
mount /dev/sda1 /myraid/boot
mount --bind /dev /myraid/dev
mount -t devpts devpts /myraid/dev/pts
mount -t proc proc /myraid/proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs /myraid/sys
chroot /myraid
apt-get install mdadm
```

apt fires-up an error and trying to reboot to the installed OS result in a black screen.

I removed my mess between each attempt with bootable gParted USB:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda2
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb1
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc1
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd1
```

I also tried using GParted instead of cfdisk ; as well as configuring my hard drives as gpt with parted:

```
sudo su
parted /dev/sdx
mklabel gpt
```

I also tried with hard drives configured as DOS. Still no joy.

Disk's syncing is rather long (4 hours) and I'm at my 12th attempt. This is a cry for help.

What am I missing ? Is the partitioning wrong ? Do I have to worship some kind of system god ?

Thanks for your help and patience!

EDIT :
My best try so far was with GPT disks, partitioned as above, installation gave me

```
"Error removing initramfs-tools:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1"
```

The boot then resulted in a black screen. Here is a dump from boot repair : http://paste2.org/P3fB5jwj

Comment: You will have to be more specific than "an error"